# Microsoft Office credential prompts

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, security, office, credentials

Microsoft Office applications  prompt for user credentials when associated file types are loaded from SharePoint (xlsx, docx, etc).  Is there any way to pass through the Windows login credentials so users do not have to type their username and passwords into each Microsoft Application?  If not – is there a setting to increase the length of time which the entered credentials are cached so that users do not feel they are constantly retyping their AD credentials?

Answer (score 1):

The Office application is trying to access the document directly from the server which has to communicate with the server to determine what type of server that's accessing the file and what web authoring protocol is available.

Anytime a new process tries to access the server, the Office application will require renegoiation.

There are different resolutions depending on if users are within the network and if direct editing is needed.

If you are in the intranet, you can configure the server to use Integrated Windows Authentication and then configure the client to enable automatic logon.  The Local Intranet zone has a default configuration of automatic logon with the current user name and password.

[image]

Source - http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_integration__sharepoint/archive/2014/02/24/users-are-prompted-for-username-and-password-when-opening-an-office-file-from-a-web-server.aspx

Comment: Thank you - In IE11 I clicked File Properties and saw that the SharePoint site is in the intranet zone.  the Logon setting is set to "Automatic logon only with current user name and password.  The user is internal, using Windows Authentication within SharePoint.   I am not able to recreate this problem - but the user experienced the problem even this morning.  I assume the Logon setting is fine as is.. any other suggestion is appreciated.  I also added, then removed the registry key from the source posted followed by a restart of WebClient each time.  Issue never recreated on my end.